# db:migrate not working after cloning the source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i cloned the sample app from https://bitbucket.org/railstutorial/sample_app_4th_ed and followed the instruction there, but `rails db:migrate` is aborting

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>rails db:migrate
    rails aborted!
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext
    C:/Sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/sample_app/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
C:/Sites/sample_app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.3/bcrypt_ext
C:/Sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Sites/sample_app/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
C:/Sites/sample_app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to uninstall bcrypt completely with:

```
gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
gem uninstall bcrypt
```

Be sure all versions are uninstalled, then run

```
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

Try to run `bundle install`. After this worked you could try to run `rake db:migrate` again.